# Get Javascript Variable value in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
    var val;
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        alert( this.value );
        val = this.value;
    })
    
    <?php
echo $variable = "<script>document.write(val)</script>";
?>
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>

</select>
```

I want to get the value of the selected box and save it in a PHP variable. I want to save and echo `val` variable. Please help

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354147/call-php-function-in-javascript/14354203#14354203

Comment: Read this: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/851432)

Comment: Then What should I do for getting selected value in a php variable

Comment: use ajax for this . php server side so need to use ajax for this condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass jQuery variables to PHP variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202070/how-to-pass-jquery-variables-to-php-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code for use variable

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['php_value'];
  ?>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function getValue(obj){
    var value = obj.value;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: "val="+ value,
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function ( result )  {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}

</script>

<select onchange="getValue(this)">
<option value="1" <?php if($_SESSION['php_value'] == 1) echo 'selected';?>>One</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($_SESSION['php_value'] == 2) echo 'selected';?>>Two</option>
<option value="3" <?php if($_SESSION['php_value'] == 3) echo 'selected';?>>Three</option>
<option value="4" <?php if($_SESSION['php_value'] == 4) echo 'selected';?>>four</option>

</select>
```

then create edit.php file

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['php_value'] = $_REQUEST['val'];
?>
```

Comment: I need a value in a php variable. So where is a variable? help me please

Comment: So great to see three levels of language nesting use the src attribute.

Comment: JavaScript inside HTML is bad. JavaScript inside HTML inside PHP is worse.

Comment: i have just answer it , this is not need to structure, when question teller use , he will use it as structure

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Thanks for your help. Your code is working fine. But I have little problem.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
when I included it in my code it reflects and dropdown is not working. and without it when i select dropdown then a popup appears and ask to reload page

Comment: which problem tell me

Comment: Do you understand my problem ? @ShafiqulIslam

Comment: can you give me your code in email or something? i think this is little problem so i can help you

Comment: My code is too large, Cant paste it here. I think there is some problem related to ajax included with jquery.

Comment: ok then can you give me your code in email? which secure code remove it and send other code

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can do this. Google it, and check out api.jquery.com and look at the ajax functions, .ajax(), .post(), .get(), .load(), etc.

As for your specific question, here is what you would do:

```
//Javascript file

$.post('my_ajax_receiver.php', 'val=' + $(this).val(), function(response) {
  alert(response);
  });
```

});

```
//PHP file my_ajax_receiver.php
<?php
   $value = $_POST['val'];
   echo "$value";
?>
```

Comment: orignal answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202070/how-to-pass-jquery-variables-to-php-variable]