# I want to check how many have selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using javascript to change the value of text from select to selected.

Now I want to add in cart which have selected text. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

PHP CODE :

```
<a class='btn slct' href='javascript:void(0)' >Select</a>
```

Javascript Code :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.slct').click(function() {
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Select' ? 'Selected' : 'Select');


        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What is the specific issue here ? The code above seems to be working

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

    var linkText = $(this).val();
    if(linkText = 'Select'){
        $(this).html('Selected');
   }
});
```

I think you should try this to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(this).val($(this).text() == 'Select' ? 'Selected' : 'Select');
```

instead of

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Select' ? 'Selected' : 'Select');
```

Comment: add explanation to why OP should use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.slct').click(function() {
       var value = [];
       var text = [];
            $(".slct:checked").each(function() {
                value.push(this.value);
                text.push('Selected');
            });

    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: 'edit.php',
    data: "value ="+ value+"&text="+text ,
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function ( result )  {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    });
       });
     });
```

change checkboxname as your name

```
  $('input[name="checkboxname"]:checked').each(function() {
   $(this).val($(this).text() == 'Select' ? 'Selected' : 'Select');
   $(this).html('Selected');
  });
```

it will return total check count

```
$('.slct').click(function () {
var check = $('.slct').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked"]').length;
alert(check);
return false;
}):
```

you can also use this

```
var check = $('.slct').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
alert(check);
```

Comment: how it will return total checked values and can i show them to cart on next page. Pl advise

Comment: total check count not work? next page mean send this value in php script for action?

Comment: There is link Check selected Values. When user click on that link I want to redirect him to new page where I want to show all the selected values by him. Can we do this? Like add to cart system

Comment: so send this all selected data using get method then in that page you find all data or add hidden form and submit it in that link . then it will solve this

Comment: but i am not using any form in this. Can we do this with any other method?

Comment: ok use ajax method send save it session and response redirect your page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555389/get-javascript-variable-value-in-php-variable/42556181#42556181

Comment: Can you plz give me the full code how to use this? Thanks

Comment: i am busy. i will do it few hour later. if you want this

Comment: Ok great... and I am using this in php while loop. Select text is in all rows. Can we do with text whenever user click select, Then text becomes selected till this its working. after that i want to show how many are selected and which are selected on next page. When user click on link to see the selection which is made by him

Comment: ok show me your checkbox form structure, you want to checkbox value with level text?

Comment: I am not using form.   <td> <input type='checkbox' class='slct' href='javascript:void(0)'></td>

Comment: Can we do with text whenever user click select? not clear which text you send? selected
$(this).val($(this).text() == 'Select' ? 'Selected' : 'Select');

Comment: have to use text with checkbox? and have to use all three functions which you have mentioned

Comment: check first function and check alert data is ok then if ok use only this

Comment: yes it shows alert data is on but how can i get these values on next page with click on link or button?

Comment: check this it will help you. use ajax and set session then you can use any page
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555389/get-javascript-variable-value-in-php-variable/42556181#42556181

Comment: check updated first function then create edit.php something like that and set value in session and click link or button then go this page then print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: can u plz help how i can use this with your function and and checkbox and how to use this in link. It would be great help for me.

Comment: please give me your html or just give me screenshot which type you want